# RxJS: Emit new value whenever all subjects emit true

Tags: rxjs, observable, subject, subject-observer

I have two subjects: `networkStateSubject` and `authStateSubject`.

`networkStateSubject` emits `boolean` value:

`true` if network connectivity is enabled,

`false` if network connectivity is disabled.

`authStateSubject` emits `boolean` value:

`true` if user logged in,

`false` if user logged out.

I need to combine these two subjects, so that **whenever both of their values are `true`, new value (`void`) is emitted from combined observable**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `combineLatest` and `filter` to check for both values.

```
const connectedAndAuth$ = combineLatest([networkStateSubject, authStateSubject])
   .pipe(
      filter(([isConnected, isAuth]) => isConnected && isAuth),
      map(_ => 1) //what do you mean emit a void value?
   );
```

Comment: Perhaps you could replace `map(_ => 1)` with `mapTo(1)`?

Comment: I mean type of emitted value needs to be void. e.g. Subject<void>, Promise<void> etc..

Answer (score 1):

I would use [combineLatest](https://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest) with a selector `networkStateSubject && authStateSubject`, and then filter the true ones